# Restoring replicated DB onto a different server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a replicated DB on one server. I backed it up then trying to restore that DB onto a different server but I keep getting this error:

[image]
What could I do to prevent this error?

Comment: How are you doing the restore? Also, is your expectation that replication would continue to work on the restored database or not?

Answer (score 0):

If you restore the database with KEEP_REPLICATION enabled to a server outside of your replication topology, then that is the error you will get. Otherwise, exclude the KEEP_REPLICATION to have the database restored with replication properties removed.